# How can I add __unicode__ to display sqlite3 informative DB info?

Tags: python, django, unicode

First I'll mention that there is no Traceback. It just doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

These are the two classes that define the models of data for the app.

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Adding the code for unicode here:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question
```

Is supposed make the Django API call return a more informative information about your objects. Here's the API call:

```
# objects.all() displays all the polls in the database. 
>>> Poll.objects.all()
```

This is the non informative return of *Poll.objects.all()* is:

```
>>> Poll.objects.all()
[<Poll: Poll object>]
```

The more informative answer which it's supposed to display after adding the unicode method is supposed to be this:

```
>>> Poll.objects.all()
[<Poll: What's up?>]
```

The problem/error I'm experiencing is that it still displays the non informative answer.

Comment: Have you restarted your interpreter and imported Poll again?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? If you're using Python 3, then you need to define `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`.

Comment: @iMom0 Thank you for that tip! I will add it as official answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encounter this problem where you've added something to your classes and it's not showing up when you run API commands. You can try the following.

1. Start your interpreter again.
2. Turn your machine off and on.
3. Possibly going back and syncing the database again.

I don't know which of these work because I did all of them at one point. But it's definitely working now. So there's nothing wrong with code indentation or anything.

**Additional answer below:**

**I found this in the  Django tutorial. It's likely the most correct answer to this problem:**

You’ll need to restart the development server to see your changes. Normally, the server auto-reloads code every time you modify a file, but the action of creating a new file doesn’t trigger the auto-reloading logic.